# call webservice funtion that has params type input by js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web-services

i have c#.net web service like this

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetReportResult(int ReportID,params object[] Parameters)
{
    return "hello";
}
[WebMethod]
public string Hello(string hello)
{
    return hello;
}
```

for hello function i can call function but GetReportResult i cant
my jquery ajax is this

```
        var webMethod = "ws.asmx/Hello";
        var parameters = "{'ReportID':10,}";
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "ws.asmx/GetReportResult",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            data: parameters,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

i want to call this web service by jquery but i don't know how to send data to params value
can everybody help me?

Comment: Just send an array, "params" just enables params arguments syntax when you call it from code - it is still a simple array. The first question which comes: why would you declare a WebMethod with params?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent the input using an array in jQuery. Here is a working sample of the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  var webMethod = "ws.asmx/Hello";
  var parameters = "{'ReportID':10,'Parameters':['Name1','Name2']}";
  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "ws.asmx/GetReportResult",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

    data: parameters,
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @mpf82 thank you my friend, i solved my question by this way and waiting to system let me to checked my answer